# How to declare a TypeScript interface or type to get take keys from a specified list, these should have objects with keys from another specified list

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to declare a typescript interface for a function that returns something like this

For BTC/USD pair it returns:

```
{
 "bitcoin": {
  "usd": 12345,
  "usd_24hr_change": -1.2345
 }
}
```

For BTC/ETH pair it returns:

```
{
 "bitcoin": {
  "eth": 12345,
  "eth_24hr_change": -1.2345
 }
}
```

For ETH/USD pair it returns:

```
{
 "ethereum": {
  "usd": 12345,
  "usd_24hr_change": -1.2345
 }
}
```

I have tried

```
interface CurrencyData {
  [id: string]: {
    [id: string]: number;
  };
}
```

But this makes it too generic, I want to have a particular number of keys. In this case we can take assume keys should be one of the following: "bitcoin", "ethereum", "usd" for first one and "usd" "usd_24hr_change", "eth" "eth_24hr_change" for the second one.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template literal type as a key, like:

```
type USD = 'usd'
type ExampleWithKey = {
  [K in `${USD}_some_suffix`]: number
}
```

So now, the `ExampleWithKey` type has a `usd_some_suffix` property.

---

This leads us to this type:

```
type CurrencyCompare<
  BaseName extends string,
  OtherAbbreviation extends string
> = {
  [KBase in BaseName]:
    { [KOther in OtherAbbreviation]: number } &
    { [KOther in `${OtherAbbreviation}_24hr_change`]: number }
}
```

This is a generic object type. It accepts a `BaseName` string literal type that is the base of the comparison ("bitcoin" in your first example), and an abbreviation for what you are comparing it to ("usd" in your first example").

With that it can create an object type with a single key for the base name, and then you can intersect two object types, each with the dynamic property that you want.

---

And now you have a strongly typed object, so long as you know the currency names ahead of time.

```
declare const comparison: CurrencyCompare<'bitcoin', 'usd'>
comparison.bitcoin.usd_24hr_change // type: number
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgJwRAdgYxDA9gWzAQ2QB4AoKKAIXwGcIA5fHaCAD2FQBNqprgEBLFAHMANGSgB5YAAsICAIIAjRcgBu-fMH5YUUVuxRcefQUJIA+KAF4oAb3EBtANJVaUQZRr1GEALoAucXJbKGcpWQR3XXC5JRUIdU1tFACoFDgcRTkoAF8oADIgu1CnGMiPAAMAElsyuLUNLR0cgH0AJgAWaQQWtGl8YQgK1PTM7JySCZIOCDQAG0JoNB1eKGW8Qn5qHX9YRGR0TFwCYgByRX5gZcFTkShTuGoOU-MSdZOtnQA6C6usQS+jw47S6PT6AyEEBIAHpoeR4QjEfCAHoAfhIJCAA)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this pattern:

```
type CurrencyKeys = "bitcoin" | "ethereum" | "usd";
type CurrencySecondLevelKeys = "usd" | "usd_24hr_change" | "eth" | "eth_24hr_change";

type CurrencyData = {
  [K in CurrencyKeys]: {
    [Key in CurrencySecondLevelKeys]?: number 
  } 
};

const btcUsd : Partial<CurrencyData>  =
{
 "bitcoin": {
  "usd": 12345,
  "usd_24hr_change": -1.2345
 }
}

const btcEth : Partial<CurrencyData> =
{
 "bitcoin": {
  "eth": 12345,
  "eth_24hr_change": -1.2345
 }
}

const ethUsd : Partial<CurrencyData> =
{
 "ethereum": {
  "usd": 12345,
  "usd_24hr_change": -1.2345
 }
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-VOkvl5qaYv3WUP3ePvb7QFP2vkAIL2Ls4yCJJfZXJZ+pqnkFJotLA7ZhPS4LDCkfKcAquegPYgRZIfVAehLlSLNEGkUg3ThbITU9LccDUONsHmRdIWrRQL3TLBkgUWErj6WRHAcR8qxcPd6wHa0qFte1mkdVkAEY-SZViIyjedA3EUAgkta4iCQZBkJEZgWXhDQAHlORUa0cB6XtqNoul6J6VloynGUeNJIgFBUZAiFkXt9ME4SiA08Rg1jSYaH2LAaCgMw0V0c4VWQUBoCYJFYFybNeLwbZYjpd9F0yHRZAMfRKl-RIcOAtNsHwepemwRgmCvRMlSg9BWE-eAWxoqwPn4QR30K5wAFptV1HB3iiqo9ykRSaWUhl6FZcMYwPZdFCQbBG3oNyqReE1ZCIIhkmtUhSEYPrYKoFMcH0bh9VmDYSC2QR3kOcgsizES9tgKphhq75xENMxQA0cgG33PKBX0FlWXgydEnXWRXqguQPuggB+TrSR2a6RGdK7EBuu7nFIWd-VZbi2VFRJ2X3Q5MCmXMw3ZRAUbRogVHoAABdkJXiOGmMRgBpLAiDRrAMamKmacwFQqEJ4nSfDRH9y2Rw3QxrB6B5yhmcJxGNBGRgvN2HAiZJzqpAAdVSbByyMNMTR6fRRGeTAiB8FDlHsfQlx9WRKEwYctcQNCzSSbMu2wZwph1vXrnofCDESctetAaEMOkDzQTcKQiDMfBWCzTVKgQMFHki-RvdV5L0Dw2QCNcbN8l-KCILqoKLlVIDLfchwongCIHEC4kzqNAAFAgrscbgaEe0Hwf-MhEhULvnsYWd-r461IAbpvnTrofhib6HHtJskwZENTiYjABWaMSZ4tcgaYxfwxXxJwwANlXmfN9X0AAGYo0SC+EfPqM2f76h9DYEgMgkrYx-2Mhm+L8fG6oBet6gAANQ-2Hv-ZigCQGDzAe1CUW8ZQA1AM-MgBhwC5g-m7IQ-poET3AXAjqwDQG4NgbAhBfFkEZC6DVegGCv7YPrsQjqpDYz-EBN7X23UDTMFyFQbQsAgIiGcIIWADIijwECOQF4n4HY-hEJQd4Pcsxa1kogfY005LKiuOdOkVcqp9EEc2KIJB+jIDLrqaaY9+Q4AAKJNH0m8egvZvLOkUZ3LuDhZBUGdKyLuKhFF9ynC4icjAZTiEEmYsEljsi2NGEQBxg4T5wNPjgv+ADmLmXCeXCxBArExPsVWBJc8t4L0SCkyeEDmKlIYakiBHVzLVwugAYR5jVZskByavG-uyZapBiCUHZKOUA7J6DzBql6AZY52TQhcOyGU2jQDNP8m0jQAgSAuAADL0DTMgDp3gWRTKoDMwZByXAAH1wzCgMDgU54isCyHoBMoZIyDCPOGRkc5lzrm3NhA80J8zFmtPgJAAAIkcCCLIuLr3Jt+BZLS3ZAt2VQCUzpIU8TZLsmFAL4VD1Wa4TZ2zEUSh+kEhCoA4bBjJcGUJiDuC9IAKqHNAKPEuFhkAAB4sVtNBeQAAfDxJk4hIXdMuH0zA7IUVwxOeK0AjFwxn2FEvNeQzpkfKuTcowPzpXlUYioOVCruKWUsmEvitL4DWKuMyxarKOVwq5WCvlAqhU9NFdK1FbyXnOllfKxVkrnmqq+Rq+5WqdV6qXgaiyFpH7AQyAy5IlqogoBtUsoF3LEAOsFdxd1aRxkSp4lKz1oalUnP9equ5DznTat1d68NwYgA)